# Fwrite does not copy all bytes in binary file copy

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I am trying to copy binary files from `src` to `dst`. This script seems to copy all of the bytes. BUT when I open both files in Hex Workshop I see that `dst` file is always missing 3 bytes at the end of the file. These 3 bytes should have been `00 00 00`, this problem prevents me from opening `dst` file.

```
void binaryCopy(char **argv) {
    int *buf = 0;
    int elements = 0;
    int size = 0, wantOverwrite = 0;
    FILE *src = fopen(argv[SRC_POS], "rb");
    FILE *dst = fopen(argv[DST_POS], "w+b");
    if (src) {
        if (dst) {
            wantOverwrite = overwrite();
        }
        if (wantOverwrite) {
            fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_END);
            size = ftell(src);
            fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            buf = (int *)malloc(size);
            elements = fread(buf, BYTE_SIZE, size / BYTE_SIZE, src);
            fwrite(buf, BYTE_SIZE, elements, dst);
            printf("copy completed");
            free(buf);
        }
    }
    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);
}
```

Comment: If this was a [mcve] we could try it ourselves, but without knowing what all of your constants are and what the functions you haven't shown do it's hard to say. Why are you not just reading and writing `size`? What happens when `size` is not an even multiple of `BYTE_SIZE`?

Comment: The first thing I notice is the complete lack of error checking. You won't get far with that. That said, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: if you need 0L instead of 0 in the fseek call you're doing i wrong,

Comment: Stranger things have happened, but are the first three bytes in your `src` file `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`? Depending on how that file was prepared/appended to, etc.., if you thing it contains all integers are you are always 3-bytes off, check for a Byte Order Mark at the beginning.

Comment: @James: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in your function as written.

- `fopen(dstFilename, "w+b");` truncates the file, so your overwrite check later is meaningless.
- You're not checking for NULL after malloc, and your buffer should be an `unsigned char*` since that is what `fread/fwrite` will interpret it as.
- At the end, both `fclose` functions could be called with NULL file pointers likely resulting in a crash. You should move them into the scopes where you know each was successfully opened.
- The big problem, the one that prompted this question, is that you are not handling cases where the size of the file is not an even multiple of whatever `BYTE_SIZE` is. Since you allocated enough memory for the whole file you should just read and write the whole file. `fread(buf, 1, size, src);` and `fwrite(buf, 1, size, dst);`. In general it is best to make the element size parameter of `fread/fwrite` 1 and the count the number of bytes you want to read or write. There's no math to go wrong, and you can tell exactly how many bytes were read/written.

Here's a version of your original function that I've corrected and annotated so it works if nothing goes wrong.

```
void originalBinaryCopy(const char *srcFilename, const char *dstFilename)
{
    //odd size to ensure remainder
    const size_t BYTE_SIZE = 777;

    int *buf = 0;
    int elements = 0;
    int size = 0, wantOverwrite = 0;
    FILE *src = fopen(srcFilename, "rb");
    //This truncates dst, so the overwirte check is meaningless
    FILE *dst = fopen(dstFilename, "w+b");
    if (src)
    {
        if (dst)
        {
            fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_END);
            size = ftell(src);
            fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            //always check for NULL after malloc - This should be a char*
            buf = (int *)malloc(size);
            if (!buf)
            {
                fclose(dst);
                fclose(src);
                return;
            }
            elements = fread(buf, BYTE_SIZE, size / BYTE_SIZE, src);
            fwrite(buf, BYTE_SIZE, elements, dst);

            //added, copy remainder
            elements = fread(buf, 1, size % BYTE_SIZE, src);
            fwrite(buf, 1, size % BYTE_SIZE, dst);
            //end

            printf("copy completed %s -> %s\n", srcFilename, dstFilename);
            free(buf);
        }
    }
    //dst could be NULL here, move inside if(dst) scope above
    fclose(dst);
    //src could be NULL here, move inside if(src) scope above
    fclose(src);

    if (comp(srcFilename, dstFilename) != 0)
    {
        printf("compare failed - %s -> %s\n", srcFilename, dstFilename);
    }
}
```

Notice how the remainder is handled at the end.

Here is how I would handle copying files along with a test suite to create, copy, and verify a set of files. It shows how to avoid truncating the destination if you don't want to and has quite a bit of error checking in the actual functions. I did not include any specific error checking on the caller side, but for real code I would have enumerated all of the possible errors and used those return values to pass to an error handling function that could print them out and possibly exit the program.

Manipulating files is one thing you want to be ***VERY*** careful about since there's potential for data loss if your code doesn't work, so before you use it with real files make sure it's 100% solid with test files.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TEST_FILE_MIN 1024
#define TEST_FILE_MAX 1024 * 1024
const char *src_pattern = "src_file_%08x.bin";
const char *dst_pattern = "dst_file_%08x.bin";

void createTestFiles(const char *pattern)
{
    char filename[256] = { 0 };
    char buffer[1024];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = rand();
    }

    for (size_t i = TEST_FILE_MIN; i <= TEST_FILE_MAX; i *= 2)
    {
        sprintf(filename, pattern, i);
        FILE *dst = fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (dst)
        {
            size_t reps = i / TEST_FILE_MIN;
            for (size_t w = 0; w < reps; ++w)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), dst);
            }
            fclose(dst);
        }
    }
}

int comp(const char *srcFilename, const char *dstFilename)
{
    FILE *src = fopen(srcFilename, "rb");
    if (!src)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    //open for reading to check for existence
    FILE *dst = fopen(dstFilename, "rb");
    if (!dst)
    {
        fclose(src);
        return -2;
    }

    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t srcSize = ftell(src);
    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fseek(dst, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t dstSize = ftell(dst);
    fseek(dst, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (srcSize == 0 || dstSize == 0 || srcSize != dstSize)
    {
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return -3;
    }

    unsigned char *srcBuf = (unsigned char *)calloc(1, srcSize);
    unsigned char *dstBuf = (unsigned char *)calloc(1, srcSize);
    if (!srcBuf || !dstBuf)
    {
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return -4;
    }

    if (fread(srcBuf, 1, srcSize, src) != srcSize)
    {
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return -5;
    }
    if (fread(dstBuf, 1, dstSize, dst) != dstSize)
    {
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return -6;
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);

    //result * 100 to make this error outside te range of the other general errors from this function.
    int result = memcmp(srcBuf, dstBuf, srcSize) * 100;
    free(srcBuf);
    free(dstBuf);

    return result;
}

void originalBinaryCopy(const char *srcFilename, const char *dstFilename)
{
    //odd size to ensure remainder
    const size_t BYTE_SIZE = 777;

    int *buf = 0;
    int elements = 0;
    int size = 0, wantOverwrite = 0;
    FILE *src = fopen(srcFilename, "rb");
    //This truncates dst, so the overwirte check is meaningless
    FILE *dst = fopen(dstFilename, "w+b");
    if (src)
    {
        if (dst)
        {
            fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_END);
            size = ftell(src);
            fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            //always check for NULL after malloc - This should be a char*
            buf = (int *)malloc(size);
            if (!buf)
            {
                fclose(dst);
                fclose(src);
                return;
            }
            elements = fread(buf, BYTE_SIZE, size / BYTE_SIZE, src);
            fwrite(buf, BYTE_SIZE, elements, dst);

            //added, copy remainder
            elements = fread(buf, 1, size % BYTE_SIZE, src);
            fwrite(buf, 1, size % BYTE_SIZE, dst);
            //end

            printf("copy completed %s -> %s\n", srcFilename, dstFilename);
            free(buf);
        }
    }
    //dst could be NULL here, move inside if(dst) scope above
    fclose(dst);
    //src could be NULL here, move inside if(src) scope above
    fclose(src);

    if (comp(srcFilename, dstFilename) != 0)
    {
        printf("compare failed - %s -> %s\n", srcFilename, dstFilename);
    }
}

int binaryCopy(const char *srcFilename, const char *dstFilename, bool overwrite)
{
    //arbitrary odd size so we can make sure we handle a partial buffer.
    //assuming the code tests successfully I'd use something like 64 * 1024.
    unsigned char buffer[7777] = { 0 };

    FILE *src = fopen(srcFilename, "rb");
    if (!src)
    {
        //Error, source file could not be opened
        return -1;
    }
    //open for reading to check for existence
    FILE *dst = fopen(dstFilename, "rb");
    if (dst)
    {
        if (!overwrite)
        {
            //Error, dest file exists and we can't overwrite it
            fclose(src);
            fclose(dst);
            return -2;
        }

        //reopen dst it for writing
        if (!freopen(dstFilename, "wb", dst))
        {
            fclose(src);
            fclose(dst);
            dst = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //it didn't exist, create it.
        dst = fopen(dstFilename, "wb");
    }

    if (!dst)
    {
        //Error, dest file couldn't be opened
        fclose(src);
        return -3;
    }

    //Get the size of the source file for comparison with what we read and write.
    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t srcSize = ftell(src);
    fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET);

    size_t totalRead = 0;
    size_t totalWritten = 0;

    size_t bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), src))
    {
        totalRead += bytesRead;
        totalWritten += fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, dst);
    }
    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);

    if (totalRead != srcSize)
    {
        //src read error
        return -4;
    }
    if (totalWritten != srcSize)
    {
        //dst write error
        return -5;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    createTestFiles(src_pattern);

    for (size_t i = TEST_FILE_MIN; i <= TEST_FILE_MAX; i *= 2)
    {
        char srcName[256];
        char dstName[256];
        sprintf(srcName, src_pattern, i);
        sprintf(dstName, dst_pattern, i);

        //use my copy to create dest file
        if (binaryCopy(srcName, dstName, true) != 0)
        {
            printf("File: '%s' failed initial copy.", srcName);
        }

        originalBinaryCopy(srcName, dstName);

        if (binaryCopy(srcName, dstName, true) != 0)
        {
            printf("File: '%s' failed overwrite copy.", srcName);
        }
        if (binaryCopy(srcName, dstName, false) == 0)
        {
            printf("File: '%s' succeeded when file exists and overwrite was not set.", srcName);
        }
        //If compare succeeds delete the files, otherwise leave them for external comparison and print an error.
        if (comp(srcName, dstName) == 0)
        {
            if (remove(srcName) != 0)
            {
                perror("Could not remove src.");
            }
            if (remove(dstName) != 0)
            {
                perror("Could not remove dst.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("File: '%s' did not compare equal to '%s'.", srcName, dstName);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully this gives you something to experiment with to make sure your copier is as good as it can be. Also worth noting, I would not distinguish copying text/binary files. Files are files and if your goal is to copy them then you should always do it in binary mode so the copy is identical. On operating systems other than Windows it wouldn't matter, but on Windows there are a number of pitfalls you can run into in text mode. Best to avoid those completely if you can.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The most probable cause for your observation is the file size is not a multiple of `BYTE_SIZE`: `fread(buf, BYTE_SIZE, size / BYTE_SIZE , src);` reads a multiple of `BYTE_SIZE` and the `fwrite` call writes the bytes read.

If `BYTE_SIZE` is `4`, as the type `int* buf = 0;` seems to indicate, and if the source file has 3 more bytes than a multiple of 4, your observations would be fully explained.

You can correct the problem by making `buf` an `unsigned char *` and changing the code to:

```
        elements = fread(buf, 1, size , src);
        fwrite(buf, 1, elements, dst);
```

Note also that there is no need to open the files in update mode (the `+` in the mode string), errors and not handled explicitly and the `fclose()` calls are misplaced.

Also it seems incorrect to truncate the destination file if `overwrite()` returns 0.

Here is a corrected version with better error handling:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int binaryCopy(char *argv[]) {
    FILE *src, *dst;
    long file_size;
    size_t size, size_read, size_written;
    int wantOverwrite;
    unsigned char *buf;

    if ((src = fopen(argv[SRC_POS], "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open input file %s: %s\n", argv[SRC_POS], strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    wantOverwrite = overwrite();
    if (!wantOverwrite) {
        fclose(src);
        return 0;
    }
    if ((dst = fopen(argv[DST_POS], "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open output file %s: %s\n", argv[DST_POS], strerror(errno));
        fclose(src);
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(src);
    fseek(src, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    size = (size_t)file_size;
    if ((long)size != file_size) {
        printf("file size too large for a single block: %ld\n", file_size);
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return -1;
    }
    buf = malloc(size);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf("cannot allocate block of %zu bytes\n", size);
        fclose(src);
        fclose(dst);
        return -1;
    }
    size_read = fread(buf, 1, size, src);
    if (size_read != size) {
        printf("read error: %zu bytes read out of %zu\n", size_read, size);
    }
    size_written = fwrite(buf, 1, size_read, dst);
    if (size_written != size_read) {
        printf("write error: %zu bytes written out of %zu\n", size_written, size_read);
    }
    if (size_written == size) {
        printf("copy completed\n");
    }
    free(buf);
    fclose(dst);
    fclose(src);
    return 0;
}
```